# Using a command in echo gives a different result

Tags: shell, freebsd, csh, subshell

I am running the following commands on FreeBSD:

```
$ cat filename | tr '\t' '\n'
#Output
DOCS     : ON

NLS      : ON

RCSI     : ON

$ echo `cat filename | tr '\t' '\n'`
#Output
DOCS     : ON NLS      : ON RCSI     : ON
```

Why is echo not displaying same as actual command output? Anything wrong with syntax in echo?

Comment: If you're using `csh`, please make that very clear in your question and add the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 1):

**For csh shell, default shell on freebsd:**

From @mateusz-piotrowski and @ismael-luceno answer:
You can't, you need another shell.
Change globaly with:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

or just add at the top of your script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

**For non default shell on freebsd:**

You need to add quotes on your sub-command:

```
echo "`cat filename | tr '\t' '\n'`"
```

It is because bash will replace \n with space when passing arguments to commands when it is not quoted

Comment: Illegal variable name error message is displayed on FreeBSD.

Comment: What shell are you using ?,
echo $SHELL

Comment: echo $SHELL gives me /bin/csh

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/284226
Someone add the same problem,
It seems that you need to set a variable and then echo:
`set var = "\`cat filename | tr '\t' '\n'\`"; echo "$var";`

Comment: No luck, same output :(

Comment: You could go for bash instead of csh, just put '#!/bin/bash' on top of your script

Comment: @izissise `bash` is not in the base system on FreeBSD. You have to install it. Additionally, I am not sure if it is placed in `/bin/bash` - [a comment here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43475/how-to-install-bash-in-freebsd) suggests `/usr/local/bin/bash`. Another option is to simply use `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike sh/ksh, the C shell will always convert newlines, you either avoid using command expansion or you work around the problem with some escaping code + substitution on the csh side.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "`cat filename | tr '\t' '\n'`"
```

Comment: Not working on FreeBSD. Result in same, displayed in one line.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the easiest way to solve it is to change your shell to `/bin/sh` which should suit you if you're familiar with Bash.

In order to change your shell run:

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Alternatively you can just type `sh` into your terminal and enjoy your interactive session in `/bin/sh`.

If you really want to use Bash however here's a thread which might be helpful: [How to Install bash on FreeBSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43475/how-to-install-bash-on-freebsd)

As a side note: it is not recommended to permanently change root's shell in FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
foreach line (`cat a | tr '\t' '\n'`")
  echo $line
end
```